# Delete a child node using RemoveChild()

Tags: c#, xml, removechild

I would like to delete just this one node, for example:

`<Sample ID="544" Type="0">Sample2</Sample>`

from this XML, for example:

```
 <Tests> <Test ID="0" AllowMultipleSelect="1">
  <Name>BaseSamples</Name>
  <Sample ID="546" Type="0">Sample1 </Sample>
  <Sample ID="135" Type="0">Sample45</Sample>
  <Sample ID="544" Type="0">Sample2</Sample>
  <Sample ID="5818" Type="0" >Sample78</Sample>
  </Test>
  </Tests>
```

so that my results something like this:

```
 <Tests> <Test ID="0" AllowMultipleSelect="1">
  <Name>BaseSamples</Name>
  <Sample ID="546" Type="0">Sample1 </Sample>
  <Sample ID="135" Type="0">Sample45</Sample>
  <Sample ID="5818" Type="0" >Sample78</Sample>
  </Test>
  </Tests>
```

I would be okay with deleting any one node at a time (since I put a loop to check for sample IDs that need to be deleted)
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

```
XmlElement el = (XmlElement)originalXml.SelectSingleNode("/Tests/Test/Sample[@id='544']");
            if (el != null) {
                el.ParentNode.RemoveChild(el);
                originalXml.Save(@"d:\file.xml");
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

Found this online with a simple search:

```
XmlNode node = document.SelectSingleNode("/Tests/Test/Sample[@id='544']");
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(t);
document.Save();
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this code but it should work.

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("file.xml");
xDoc.RemoveChild(xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Sample[@ID='554']"));
```